# Twillio Error: Unable to connect: Can't find service instance with unique name 'default'

Tags: twilio-programmable-chat

I have a twillio token https://jsfiddle.net/Simon060694/nzox9du4/15/, but when trying to create a client got  `Error: Unable to connect: Can't find service instance with unique name 'default'`. What does it mean?